# Definition of bounder linear functional

Tags: functional-analysis

A bounded linear functional $f$ is a bounded linear operator (with properties of linear wich I will omite) with range in the scalar field of the normed space X in which the domain $D(f)$ lies. Thus there exist a real number c such that for all $x \in D(f)$,

$$|f(x)| \leq c||x||$$

I can't go through this definition without feeling a great discomfort. Why wasn't it simply defined as |f(x)|<c? What is the role of the vector's modulus?

My natural definition would be

$$|f(x)|\leq c$$
for all $x$.

Comment: First, what is known of $D(f)$? Are you assuming it to be bounded, so that $||x||$ has a finite supremum in $D(f)$?

Comment: Note that if have some $x_0$ with $f(x_0)\ne 0$, then $f(cx_0) = cf(x_0)$. Now, as $c\to\infty$, what happens to $\|f(cx_0)\|$?

Comment: I see the problem now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you are talking in a Banach space over $\mathbb{R}.$

Since a linear functional satisfies
$$f(ax) = af(x)$$
for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$, a linear functional satisfying your definition does not exist (except for the trivial functional $f\equiv 0$. Indeed, assume that $|f(x)|<c$ for all $x$. We may assume without loss of generality that $c>1.$ Replacing $x$ with $cx$, we have $|cf(x)|<c$, i.e. $|f(x)|<1.$ Replacing again, we have $|f(x)|<1/c$. Eventually, by repeating this process, we conclude that $|f(x)|$ is smaller than any positive number...